# AndEngine - Performance problems with many entities

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, entity, andengine

I'm developing a rolling scene based game
I'm loading all the entities from a XML file and create them in the Loading Scene
recently I increase the game width , and by doing so , in the whole level I have about 300 entities (instead of 100+-)
But this cause a performance problems , the game is "Lagging"  \ "jumping" and everything move slow.

I'm loading the entities with the "LevelLoader".

I tried to add:

```
levelObject.setCullingEnabled(true);
```

before returning the object in :

```
public IEntity onLoadEntity(final String pEntityName, final Attributes pAttributes){...}
```

and also set Dithering in the engineOptions:

```
engineOptions.getRenderOptions().setDithering(true);
```

but it didn't help...

I'm implementing the sprite creating from XML as Matin does in his Tutorial:

http://www.matim-dev.com/full-game-tutorial---part-11.html

Is there a better way to handle such multy entities?
or a better why to improve the performance?

Comment: How do u load the image resources?Are you using sprite pool?

Comment: I'm not using a sprite Pool
I'm iterating all the XML
and creating a new sprite evry time

I didn't realize how to use the pool since I'm not creating the sprite when I'm firing an event (such as firing a bullet in a game)
I need to see the sprite when the player is moving in the sense